# 4 tabs data goes disappers

Tags: android

I have problems with android tabs, when I loaded first time it loads perfectly, but when I go to third tab and come back to again first tab, then all data get disappeared?

This is my tabbed fragment.

```
package com.autoxtion.autoconnect;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by NKCSL0015 on 9/23/2016.
 */
public class HomeActivity extends Fragment {

    View root;

    FrameLayout simpleFrameLayout;
    private View categoryView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.heart,
            R.drawable.user,
            R.drawable.heart
    };


    public HomeActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_content, null);

       // toolbar = (Toolbar) root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();



        return root;
    }


    private void setupTabIcons() {
        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("Vehicle");
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.car, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("Promotion");
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.promotiontab1, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabThree.setText("Request");
        tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.request_tab, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

        TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabFour.setText("Appointment");
        tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.appointment, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new VehicleFragmentTab(), "Vehicle");
        adapter.addFrag(new PromotionFragment(), "Promotion");
        adapter.addFrag(new RequestFragment(), "Request");
        adapter.addFrag(new AppointmentFragment(), "Appointment");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        if(RequestEditActivity.requestEditFlag==1){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
        if(AvailActivity.addpromotionrequest==1){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
        if(RequestAdapter.deleteflag==1){
            RequestAdapter.deleteflag = 0;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
        if(VehcleAdapter.deleteVehicle == 1){
            VehcleAdapter.deleteVehicle = 0;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
       /* if(CreateRequest.addrequestflag==1){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }*/
        if(CreateRequest.successfullyadd==1){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
        if(VehicleDetails.updatesuccessfully==1){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
        if(AddVehicle.successfullyaddvehicle==1){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        for (Fragment fragment : getFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            if (fragment instanceof VehicleFragmentTab || fragment instanceof PromotionFragment || fragment instanceof RequestFragment || fragment instanceof AppointmentFragment) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(fragment);
                ft.attach(fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```